# How to change state of component from button click event of another component?

Tags: reactjs

> I have "updates" button in my component. Clicking on this "updates" button my application
> scrolls down to a particular Parent section.This Parent section has been display on
> the page by another component.This Parent section contains the toggle button and using this toggle button application shows/hide another child sections within this Parent section.I have to show this child sections on clicking "updates" button.In short I have to call toggle method of sibling component's child component from another component.
>
> My Headerbox.js contains the "updates" button which calls gotoUpdatesWeekSection() function and application scrolls down to section "updatesInWeek".
> Blockquote

My Headerbox.js File contains updates button and scroll function as follows:

```
<div className={keyUpdateBtnstitle}>
    <a className={scUpdateBtn} href="javascript:void(0);" onClick={()=>gotoUpdatesWeekSection()}>2 updates</a>
</div>

function gotoUpdatesWeekSection(){
     scrollToElement('#updatesThisWeek', {offset:-90})
    }
```

And application scroll down to below section which is in UpdatesSection.js file.

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react'
import {toggle_button, item_container, item_container_big, containerFilter, itemFilter, innerSize, layerOneDiv, learnMoreLink} from './layerOneBoxItem.css'

export default class LayerOneBoxItem extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        toggle:false
    };

    this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
  }
 
  toggle(e){
    e.preventDefault()
      this.setState({toggle:!this.state.toggle})
     
  }
  renderToggleButton(){
    if (this.state.toggle === false){
        return <button className={toggle_button} onClick={this.toggle}>
        See why
        </button>
    }else{
        return <button className={toggle_button} onClick={this.toggle}>Collapse</button>
    }
  }
  
  
  renderItemSmall(){
    if (!this.state.toggle){
     return (
            <div className={item_container} onClick={this.toggle}>

             //code to display small section
                 
             </div>
        )
   }
  }
  renderItemBig(){
    if (this.state.toggle){
     return (
            <div className={item_container_big}>

              //code to display big section

             </div>
        )
   }
  }
  render() {
    return (
            <div>
             {this.renderItemSmall()}
             {this.renderItemBig()}
             </div>
        )
  }
}
```

Main file which displays this components are as follows :

```
import {UpdatesSection,HeaderBox} from 'components'
return (
        <div className="wrapper">
        <HeaderBox 
        data={headerData} 
        braintree={props.braintree} 
        uid={props.uid} 
        viewedCardsInMonth={props.viewedCardsInMonth} 
        scUpdatesCount={props.scUpdatesCount} 
        getUserSCRatings={props.getUserSCRatings}/>

       <UpdatesSection 
                uid={props.uid} 
                ticker={props.stockcard.ticker} 
                scUpdatesCount={props.scUpdatesCount} 
                scUpdatesInWeek={props.scUpdatesInWeek}  
                analystconsensus={props.stockcard.analystRecommendation}
                getUserSCRatings={props.getUserSCRatings}
                scUpdatesRating={props.scUpdatesRating}
                ticker={props.stockcard.ticker} 
                braintree={props.braintree} 
                subscribedCards={props.subscribedCards} 
                getUserSubscribedCards={props.getUserSubscribedCards} 
                gotoLoginPage={props.gotoLoginPage} 
                gotoSignupPage={props.gotoSignupPage}
                />
    </div>
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

For calling toggle method in your children component you have to do the following changes:

**1. In your Main file make these changes**

Make one method that calls when you click on the 'updates' button like this and pass the method to the *Header* Component as a prop.

1. `callToggleMethod(){ this.updateSectionRef.toggle(); }`
2. `<HeaderBox callToggleMethod={this.callToggleMethod}/>`
3. `<UpdatesSection ref={c = {this.updateSectionRef = c; }}/>`

**2. Change your update button method**

`function gotoUpdatesWeekSection(){
     scrollToElement('#updatesThisWeek', {offset:-90})
this.props.callToggleMethod();
    }`

Now, when you click on Header Component 'updates' button then first it will call its parent component method which is `callToggleMethod` and we make on ref to your `UpdatesSection` component via this ref it can access your any method in the `UpdatesSection`.